# How is Lorentz Force $BQv=BIl$?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electricity, electric-current, charge

The formula for Lorentz Force on moving charge is $$F=BQv$$ which for current carrying wire is modified to $$F=BQv$$$$=BQ\frac lt$$$$=BIl$$
Where $l$ is the length of the wire inside the magnetic field.

My question arises in the fact that:

- How can we use the $t$ in velocity to divide by $Q$ and get $I$? As far as I know, in $I=\frac Qt$, $t$ is the time taken by unit charge to travel one complete revolution around the circuit(I know the formal definition is number of charge flowing through cross section area of wire in unit time, but that implies the same thing). So if I divide $Q$ by $t$ in the expression $BQv$, it implies that the $t$ is time taken to travel round the entire circuit, which is not the case as $l$ is mentioned in my book to be length of wire inside the field only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec{F} = Q (\vec{V} × \vec{B})$

When Q isnt a point charge, but a distribution, it follows that

$Q= \int \lambda dl$

Where $\lambda$ is linear charge density

"Substituting" into the lorentz force

We get

$\vec{F} = \int \lambda (\vec{V} × \vec{B}) dl $

We know that $\vec{I} = \lambda \vec{V}$

So,

$\vec{F} = \int (\vec{I} × \vec{B}) dl $

Because $\vec{I}$ always follows dl (in the same direction), we can change vector current to scalar current, and scalar dl to vector dl

$\vec{F} = \int (I \vec{dl} × \vec{B})  $

Or if I is constant

$\vec{F} =  I \int ( \vec{dl} × \vec{B})$

If $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{dl}$ are perpendicular always,

$\vec{F} =  I \int   |\vec{B}| |\vec{dl}| $

If $|\vec{B}|$ is constant, it is independant of the integral, thus

$\vec{F} = |\vec{B}| I \int |\vec{dl}|$

$F =|\vec{B}| I  L$

Or $F=BIL$